# Error while calling a function (pointer and vector)

Tags: c, vector, initialization, warnings, ansi-c

Suppose that in the main I have a function `a`:

```
a(c);
```

and `c` is declared like

```
char* c.
```

The function a is actually like this:

```
void a(char* v)
{
    v[0] = 1;
    v[1] = 2;
}
```

Is this wrong? Because the program is saying that `c` is uninitialized in this function.

EDIT:
More code:

```
byte* msg;

insere_msg(t_msg, argv[2], msg);

void insere_msg(int size, char name[MAX], byte* v)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i = 10;
    int n = 0;
    char aux;

    v[0] = (byte) 4;
    v[1] = (byte) 8;
    v[2] = (byte) 15;
    v[3] = (byte) 16;
    v[4] = (byte) 23;
    v[5] = (byte) 42;
    v[6] = (byte) size>>(3*8);
    v[7] = (byte) size>>(2*8);
    v[8] = (byte) size>>(1*8);
    v[9] = (byte) size;

    fp = fopen(name, "r");

    while(n < size)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%c", &aux);
        v[i] = (byte) aux;
        i++;
        n++;
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you passing in as V?  Have you declared this variable and initialized memory for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at your edit:
You will need to allocate the memory using the malloc command somewhere.

```
msg = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * atLeastThree);
```

Now that msg is allocated, it can be pushed into your insere_msg function and your a function.

You should also implement this more "safe" code:

```
void a(char * v, unsigned int sizeofV){
    if(NULL != v && sizeofV >= 3){
        v[0] = 1;
        v[2] = 2;
    }else{
        printf("array v is either not allocated or not of proper size");
    }
}
```

you really SHOULD check to make sure that a point type has been initialized and that it is valid for the purpose of the function you are trying to pursue, before you manipulate the data being pointed to by the pointer!!!

NOW, this will not SOLVE the problem if you have not allocated the memory, it will simply keep it from erring out.

If you want to have EVEN SAFER code, you will pass in the unallocated pointer, and the let the function allocate and return the size.  The only thing here is, that the caller if responsible for deallocating the memory.

```
unsigned int a(char * v){

    v = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * Necessity);

    if(NULL != v){
        v[0] = 1;
        v[2] = 2;
    }else{
        printf("array v is either not allocated or not of proper size");
    }

    return Necessity;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof v` will return the size of a `char *`, usually 4 or 8. Determining the size of the pointed-to memory block from a pointer is impossible.

Comment: AHHH, long time for my C skeels, you are correct, will change my answer. :-)  Love this site, I keep learning over again all the things I used to know off the top of my head.